# Disable rich:listShuttle

Tags: list, jsf, richfaces, shutil

I need to disable listshuttle control components.

that is, i need to display the following components ..copy, copy all remove and remove all, and First, up down and last.

But **disable** to all the above components.

```
<rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{Shuttle1.sourceStrList}"
                  targetValue="#{Shuttle1.destStrList}"
                  var="items"
                  listsHeight="150"
                  sourceListWidth="130"
                  targetListWidth="130"
                  sourceCaptionLabel="Available Items"
                  targetCaptionLabel="Currently Active Items">

              <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{items}" />
              </rich:column>
</rich:listShuttle>
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine buttons in facets, and then set the disabled attribute on the new buttons.